# Face Logon using Credential provider using vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on Face recognition logon using credential provider, i am having the c++ code of the credential provider and added the code to display the webcam, it is displaying the window but not the camera in the window. Any suggestions/samples on credential provider to develop the face logon using c++.

Thanks in Advance.